# Preventing an Android ListView from taking up almost all of the screen height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to setup an activity in Android that has 50% of the screen hight for a ScrollView and the other 50% for a ListView.

To do this I have set the weight of each to "1".

Like This:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="10dip">


    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/my_table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="0">

            <TableRow android:padding="5dip"
        android:id="@+id/fault_heading"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/table_title"
        android:paddingRight="20dip"/>

            </TableRow>
            <!-- More rows are added at run time. -->

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/comments"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dip"
          android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

When both the ScrollView and the ListView have too much content to display without scrolling this works perfectly.

When the ScrollView only needs 20% of the screen and the ListView needs 70% the ListView grows to 70% so it can display without scrolling. This is not what I expected to happen but is good.

The problem I have is when the ListView has so much data that it would need the whole screen to display AND the Scroll view only 1 or 2 rows of data in it. In this case the ListView grows to take up almost the full height and leaves space equivalent to about one line of text for the scroll view.

I can't seem to get my head around how to reserve a certain proportion of the screen for the ScrollView no matter how big the ListView gets.

The amount of space the ScrollView can grab seems directly proportional to the number of rows in it's child table. When this is only 1 the scroll view is only about half a cm in height.

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to solve the issue, but you don't need the two `LinearLayout` wrapping the two inner views (weight works in any child of a `LinearLayout`), and I would try to set the root layout's height to `fill_parent`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Offending layouts removed. But you're quite right, this does not fix the issue.

Comment: Could you edit the question to use your new layouts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about changing `android:layout_height` for to be a minimum value instead of `0dip`?

UPDATED: As per the comments below the solution was to set the outer LinearLayout to have height "fill_parent"

Comment: Setting a height value other than 0 fixes the height of the views to that exact height rather that a proportion of the available screen.  I think I'll just have to give them fixed heights that best fit the screen.  Wanted to avoid doing that but it's not the end of the world.

Comment: You may also need to set your outer LinearLayout to have height fill_parent.

Comment: spot on. Changing the parent LinearLayout height to fill_parent made the weight values have the effect I was expecting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use these parameters in the ListView section

```
 android:layout_height="0dp" 
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: As per the code sample in the question, the attributes and values you mention were already present in the ListView element. The solution, as already provided, was to set the layout_height attribute of the LinearLayout to fill_parent.